# How to fix the input() function in python

Tags: python

I use google colab to run this code, it gets a problem but when I run it in jupyter notebook, it seems ok. I don't know why. Someone can help me. Thanks a lot.

```
tokens = input("Enter a number: ")
tokens = tokens.split()
a = int(tokens[0])
b = int(tokens[1])
print(a + b)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-67bc049ba749> in <module>()
----> 1 tokens = input("Enter a number: ")
      2 tokens = tokens.split()
      3 a = int(tokens[0])
      4 b = int(tokens[1])
      5 print(a + b)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Did you overwrite `input` somewhere by using something like `input = ...`? A notebook like Colab will remember that. You can try `del input` to clear your overwrite.

Comment: what input you are giving as we cannot split a no